# How to find count of column, based on 3 distinct values of 3 columns in Sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregate-functions

[image: My table look like this, It has 200 rows]

I need to count the no.of rooms in eachbuilding, each floor and in each zone..(like this in below picture)
[image]

I have tried using distinct and group by, but I am not getting required result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not supplied the actual SQL you have trued, but something like this should work (obviously with the correct field / table names)

```
SELECT BuildingNo, Floor, Zone, COUNT(Rooms) AS NoOfRooms
FROM myTable
GROUP BY BuildingNo, Floor, Zone
ORDER BY BuildingNo, Floor, Zone
```

Comment: thank you this is working fine, I have added one more column( NoOfRooms/8 as requiredLabor), but the problem is I need to roundup the value(for example NoOfRooms=25 then I should get "4')

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012 you can use the ROUNDUP function, else use the CEILING function like this: SELECT CEILING(25.0/8.0) (Note how I am using floats rather than integers).  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216506/rounding-up-in-sql-server

Comment: select *, CEILING(NoOfRooms/8) as Labourcount from (another select Query)y order by BuildingNo, FloorNo, Zone...this is not rounding up.
If I use CEILING(NoOfRooms/8 as float) as Labourcount...then it is giving error

Comment: Try: select *, CEILING(NoOfRooms/8.0) as Labourcount